# Deadlock caused by retried INSERTs

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-deadlocks

The following sproc attempts to insert a row into a table and generate a random ID, which is used for a PK on the corresponding table. Collisions with randomly generated IDs are handled in the catch block, where the procedure is retried/called again. Now, this takes a long time and causes deadlocks, because locks are kept for an extended period of time. Is there a way to release deadlocks immediately before retrying, so that there is a short window when other threads can succeed in locking the PK index?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addPerson
    (
        @FirstName nvarchar(100),
        @LastName nvarchar(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PersonId int

    -- generate random PersonId
    -- this sproc can generate ids that already exist in the table
    EXEC generateRandomPersonId @PersonId=@PersonId OUTPUT

    BEGIN TRY       
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] 
        (
            PersonId,FirstName,LastName
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            @PersonId,@FirstName,@LastName
        )

    BEGIN CATCH
        -- 
        -- HOW TO RELEASE LOCKS HERE that are still held
        -- for the previous INSERT statement?
        --

        DECLARE @ErrorNumber int, @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)
        SELECT  @ErrorNumber=ERROR_NUMBER(), 
                @ErrorMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()

        -- if a race condition happened and 
        -- PersonId happened to be picked already, retry all over again
        IF (@ErrorNumber = 2601 OR @ErrorNumber = 2627 AND CHARINDEX(N'PK_Persons_PersonId', @ErrorMessage) > 0)
            BEGIN
               --
               -- RETRYING HERE participates in a high possibility and 
               -- occurrence of deadlocks
               -- 
               EXEC addPerson @FirstName,@LastName
            END
            ELSE 
               -- some other error, rethrow it
               EXEC rethrowError
            END
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: is this for a comercial or production environment product?

Comment: How come there can be several error codes for a unique constraint violation? I don't know SQL server at all, just curious

Comment: Why not to use [transactions](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/02/24/exception-handling-in-t-sql-try-catch-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx)? Begin transaction before `try` and rollback where you write comment_ HOW TO RELEASE ... .

Comment: And also recursion is not needed, you can rewrite procedure and use a loop. Remember that recursion increases stack.

Comment: Why don't you check if the generated id already exists in your table **before** trying to do and `INSERT`?

Comment: Why not just just use an Identity column for the PersonID?  It is guaranteed to be unique and will take less space?  You can just use a simple TSQL insert and it will return 1 if is was sucessful.  You can can get the identity using select @@identity.

Comment: BalamBalam: the Id is randomly generated for security reasons, so it is not predictable. 

danihp: will try your recommendations, thx 

fge: the error has to be rethrown just in case something else goes wrong, the layer above can get it

Comment: OK but then you can use GUID and get a statistically unique ID.  Random may not be predictable but open to a loop to find matches.

Comment: Your security is via int as obscurity.  It would only take minutes to loop through every possible int (4.3 million).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process does not block on its own locks.  Since a call to a stored procedure runs in the same process, it's impossible for the second `insert` to wait for a lock from the first `insert`.

Could you post a deadlock graph?  That shows a lot of information on the blocking processes.

As a quick fix, you could search for a free ID in a loop, which would avoid most (but not all) possible clashes:

```
while 1=1
    begin
    EXEC generateRandomPersonId @PersonId=@PersonId OUTPUT
    if not exists (select * from Persons where PersonId = @PersonID)
        break
    end
```

Comment: +1 - This is absolutely what the op should do, search for a free Id and then do his `INSERT`

Comment: it does not block on itself, but rather with another procedure that needs to obtain a lock on the PK index. As for checking whether generated id does not exist, it won't guarantee uniqueness, since it won't be thread-safe.

Comment: Added a check to verify the id is not taken and substituted the recursion call with a loop and voila! thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope this procedure will works only in academic environment, not in a commercial product or real production environment.

This is a approach:

- replace recursion by a loop
- use transactions

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addPerson
    (
        @FirstName nvarchar(100),
        @LastName nvarchar(100)
    )
AS

BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @doed bit

  set @doed = 0

  DECLARE @PersonId int

  WHILE @doed = 0

  BEGIN
    -- generate random PersonId
    -- this sproc can generate ids that already exist in the table
    EXEC generateRandomPersonId @PersonId=@PersonId OUTPUT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION ExceptionHandling
    BEGIN TRY       

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] 
            (
                PersonId,FirstName,LastName
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                @PersonId,@FirstName,@LastName
            )
            COMMIT TRANSACTION ExceptionHandling
        BEGIN CATCH

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ExceptionHandling
            -- 
            -- HOW TO RELEASE LOCKS HERE that are still held
            -- for the previous INSERT statement?
            --

            DECLARE @ErrorNumber int, @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)
            SELECT  @ErrorNumber=ERROR_NUMBER(), 
                    @ErrorMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()

                        -- if a race condition happened and 
            -- PersonId happened to be picked already, retry all over again
            IF !(@ErrorNumber = 2601 OR @ErrorNumber = 2627 AND CHARINDEX(N'PK_Persons_PersonId', @ErrorMessage) > 0)
                BEGIN
                   --
                   -- RETRYING HERE participates in a high possibility and 
                   -- occurrence of deadlocks
                   set @doed = 0
                END
                ELSE 
                   -- some other error, rethrow it
                   set @doed = 1
                   EXEC rethrowError
                END
        END CATCH
  END  --end while
 END
GO​
```

disclaimer: not tested